# Angular 2: redirecting through component.ts

Tags: angular

I am trying to tell my component to redirect to a page in the ngOnInit() function but it doesnt work. My code looks something like this:

```
constructor(private router: Router) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.initForm();
}

initForm(){
  this.router.navigateByUrl('ng/loan/loan');
}
```

The code above will not make the component redirect me to my desired path, but if i add a button in my template file and give it `(click)="initForm()"` it does. What am i missing here?

Comment: What about `this.router.navigateByUrl('/ng/loan/loan');`? (with leading slash). You'll need to provide more information, otherwise it's unlikely that anyone can provide support (like how do the routes look like, what component contains above code, ...)

Comment: You are not getting any error messages? Maybe something like this `this.router.navigate(['ng', 'loan', 'loan']);`

Comment: I'm not getting any error messages. Everyting is fine, it just won't actually trigger the navigation. @Kyrsberg i have tried this.router.navigate(['ng', 'loan', 'loan']) also, it won't trigger, but it doesnt give any error message either. It only triggers if i call the function from a button with a (click) event.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is that you haven't imported OnInit from @angular/core

Answer (score 0):

So after doing some research i found out how to achieve desired effect. The reason calling this.initForm() from the ngOnInit() function didnt trigger the routing was because this.router.navigateByUrl is a promise. I had to add a .then() to the promise and tell it again to navigate to the route i wanted.

the new initForm() function:

```
initForm(){
  this.router.navigateByUrl('ng/loan/loan').then(x => {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('ng/loan/loan');
  })
}
```